# Compute solution to $ dX_t = X_t W_t dW_t $

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Hi I think i might have spotted an errata in my SDE textbook but I don't feel confident enough to confirm it. The question is compute
$$
dX_t = X_tW_tdW_t
$$
$W_t$ being the wiener process.

The textbook's answer is 
$$
X_t  =  exp( W_t^ 2 /2 - t/2)
$$
which is obviously wrong if we differentiate using Ito's formula (unless i am missing something).

In any case, I am wondering if there is a method to solve this SDE systematically. I have tried integration factor method, exact method, inspection and I still can't find the solution. Any input appreciated.

Comment: If you consider $d(\ln X_t)$, you should be able to get a solution for $X_t$ that involves $\int_0^t W_s^2\, ds$.

Comment: wow ok thanks. How did you come up with that guess?

Comment: It's a quite common tactic, also used for solving the [geometric brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) stochastic differential equation. One intuition for why we might want to guess to consider it is that for our given SDE, we have $\dfrac{dX_t}{X_t} = W_t \, dW_t$. The left-hand side should remind you of $d(\ln X_t)$ since in classical calculus,  $\dfrac{dx}{x} = d(\ln x)$.